# Minimum Radius vector of curve

Tags: derivatives, inequality, solution-verification, maxima-minima

Find minimum distance from origin of curve
$${a^2\over x^2}+{b^2\over y^2}=1$$

I know solution of this using derivative and answer is $a+b$ .
But what is wrong with this method

Let some random point of curve $({a\over \cos t},{b\over \sin t})$. since symmetric around all axes consider first quadrant . Now using AM-GM inequality$$r^2={a^2\over \cos^2t}+{b^2\over \sin^2t}\geq \frac{2ab}{\sin t \cos t}$$
$$r^2\geq{4ab \over \sin2t}\geq 4ab$$
$$r\geq 2\sqrt{ab}$$

This seems so legit and intuitive and right . How it's wrong ? How can I avoid such mistake in exam ?

Comment: You've found a lower bound. Recall that the minimum is the **greatest lower bound**, which means that equality must be achieved at each step. Can it be achieved? If so, at what values? (This is the misconception that you have, and how you can avoid such a mistake)  $\quad$ Note that since $ a+b \geq 2 \sqrt{ab}$, there is no contradiction so for.

Comment: Equality sign is achieved when both are equal so why can't here be$$tan t = {b\over a }$$

Comment: That's for the first inequality. What other inequalities did you use, and what are those equality conditions? Multiple conditions might contradict each other, which is why equality cannot hold throughout.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain $r\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$, you considered two inequalities as follows
$$r^2{={a^2\over \cos^2t}+{b^2\over \sin^2t}\\\ge \frac{2ab}{\sin t \cos t}\\={4ab \over \sin2t}\\\geq 4ab}$$
which, if supposed to be the *true* minimum of the problem, must lead to a condition that *all the inequalities hold with equality simultaneously which is not the case here in general*. The reason is that the inequalities ${a^2\over \cos^2t}+{b^2\over \sin^2t}\ge \frac{2ab}{\sin t \cos t}$ and ${4ab \over \sin2t}\geq 4ab$ hold with equality when $|\tan t|=|\frac{b}{a}|$ and $\sin 2t=1$, respectively. These conditions hold simultaneously only if $|a|=|b|$.